# How can I animate a react.js component onclick and detect the end of the animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have a react component flip over when a user clicks on the DOM element. I see some documentation about their animation mixin but it looks to be set up for "enter" and "leave" events. What is the best way to do this in response to some user input and be notified when the animation starts and completes? Currently I have a list item and I want it to flip over an show a few buttons like delete, edit, save. Perhaps I missed something in the docs.

animation mixin

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

Comment: I don't think there's a way of doing this without using horrible jQuery animations to catch the start/end in javascript.  If you're not adverse to using those animations then they will work... it's just not very nice :P

Comment: @mike-driver As of 2016 that is not true. jQuery will work, but it's not necessary. See my answer.

Comment: @MikeDriver in general, anything done in jQuery can be done without jQuery, it's built on the javascript so jQuery has acces to the same API:s as javascript

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Upon clicks you can update the state, add a class and record the `animationend` event.

```
class ClickMe extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { fade: false }
  }
  render() {
    const fade = this.state.fade

    return (
      <button
        ref='button'
        onClick={() => this.setState({ fade: true })}
        onAnimationEnd={() => this.setState({ fade: false })}
        className={fade ? 'fade' : ''}>
        Click me!
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

See the plnkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/gbt0W4SQhnZILlmQ?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview

*Edit*: Updated to reflect current React, which supports animationend events.

Comment: such answers to use jquery i propose to d unappropriate because react has its own ways to handle events by its own.

Comment: For anyone who still gets stuck like me. Maybe you are using transition and you need onTransitionEnd instead.

Answer (score 24):

React uses synthetic events, which includes animation events. Documention found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#animation-events. I updated the accepted answer below:

```
class ClickMe extends React.Component {
  state = {fade: false};

  render () {
    const {fade} = this.state;

    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => this.setState({fade: true})}
        onAnimationEnd={() => this.setState({fade: false})}
        className={fade ? 'fade' : ''}>
          Click me!
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: how to pass animation's name, because i have "fade in"  and "fade out" animations.
i want to run my func after 'fade out' animation end. So where should i place animation name ```onAnimationEnd={() => this.setState({fade: false})}``` here?

Answer (score 5):

How to do it with Hooks and prevState so as to not update state inside your event handlers.

```
 import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Animation() {
  const [fade, setFade] = useState(false)
  
  const triggerFade = () => {
    setFade(prevState => {
      return !prevState
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div
      onAnimationEnd={triggerFade}
      className={fade ? 'fadedClass' : 'visibleClass'}
    >
      Watch me fade
    </div>
    <button onClick={triggerFade}>Click Me</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the accepted answer, maybe this is more in-line with the new version?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer using pure Reactjs events without any JQueries, other libs, registrations or sms :)

The key point is to provide animation keyframe name as a function parameter

### CSS

```
.Modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.ModalOpen {
    animation: openModal 0.4s ease-out forwards;
}
.ModalClosed {
    animation: closeModal 0.4s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes openModal {
    0% { transform: translateY(-100%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0);   }
}

@keyframes closeModal {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-100%);}
}
```

### JS

```
const modal = ({ 
  isShown, isMounted, 
  initiateUnmountAction, unmountAction
}) => {
  const cssClasses = [
    "Modal",
    props.isShown ? "ModalOpen" : "ModalClosed"
  ];
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isMounted && <div className={cssClasses.join(' ')}
        onAnimationEnd={event => 
          {event.animationName == "closeModal" && unmountAction}
      }>
        <h1>A Modal</h1>
        <button className="Button" onClick={initiateUnmountAction}>
          Dismiss
      </button>
      </div>}
    </Fragment>

  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Most popular and easy to use package I came across:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-transition-group

Install:

```
npm install react-transition-group
```

Usage:

```
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

<CSSTransition
  in={toShow} // boolean value passed via state/props to either mount or unmount this component
  timeout={300}
  classNames='my-element' // IMP!
  unmountOnExit
>
  <ComponentToBeAnimated />
</CSSTransition>
```

NOTE: Make sure to apply below styles using the class property in CSS:

```
.my-element-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.my-element-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
.my-element-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-element-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `React`, but if it uses `CSS3 animations/transitions`, you might be able to do something like this:

```
 element.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) { 

   console.log( 'Complete');

 }, false );
```

Comment: React uses a virtual DOM. I was hoping there was a way built into React so I did not have to fiddle with the DOM directly

Comment: If you're going to animate something the user sees, you're going to have to touch the DOM. There's no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used this [project](https://github.com/pleasetrythisathome/react.animate) in my react-hammer integration [project](https://github.com/lapanoid/reactjs-hammerjs) there are some examples with hammer events and react animation.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done using CSS,

`If` you are using TailwindCSS, the answer would be, Add below Classes

```
hover:opacity-90 focus:opacity-100
```

`else` raw css

```
.class-name:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.class-name:focus{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was realise in that way, hope it's help someone.

CSS:

```
.mainStyle {
  /*some-styles*/
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

.openAnimation {
  animation: open-menu .4s linear forwards;
}

.closeAnimation {
  animation: close-menu .4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes open-menu {
  0% {width: 0;} /*You can use animation what do You need*/
  100% {width: 80%;}
}

@keyframes close-menu {
  0% {width: 80%;}
  100% {width: 0;}
}
```

JSX file

```
Import React, { useState } from React;

const AnimatedMenu = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const animationEndHandler = ({ animationName }) => {
    if (animationName === 'open-menu') {
        setOpen(true);
    }

    if (animationName === 'close-menu') {
        setOpen(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div 
        onAnimationEnd={(event) => animationEndHandler(event)}
        className={isOpen ? 'mainStyles open' : 'mainStyles close'}
      >
        hide/show
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>click me</button>
    </>
  );
};
```