# animate when clicked react animate.css

Tags: reactjs

I’ve got such a div, and me need when clicked on div animate it (add class "flip animated")

```
<div className="ui card" onClick={this.reverse}>
    <h1 className="ui header text-center">{this.get_word()}</h1>
</div>
```

what best way to do this ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Hello, please review the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask topic and correct your question.

Comment: hello,  what exactly to correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the "best" way to do it, but this way works for me :

First, add a state to your component, that will allow you to track if your div has to be animated or not :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    isAnimated: false
  } ...
```

Then create a function inside your component that will toggle "isAnimated" :

```
  // Arrow function for binding
  toggleAnimation = () => {
    this.setState({isAnimated: !this.state.isAnimated});
  }
```

Then you can add this function to your onClick event, and apply your animation class depending on the state :

```
<div 
className={`ui card ${this.state.isAnimated && "your-animation-class"}`} 
onClick={this.toggleAnimation}
>
    <h1 className="ui header text-center">{this.get_word()}</h1>
</div>
```

So when you click on your div, it will toggle isAnimated; and if isAnimated is true, your div will have the class "your-animation-class" (flip animated, I believe) applied.

Hope this helps !

Comment: how to remove class after the animation is complete ?

Comment: When you click again on the div, it will toggle "isAnimated" (set it to false) and this will remove the class, is this what you mean ?

Comment: me need start animation after each click
I solved my problem like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929961/11088733