# How to animate refresh icon on Click in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

In my react app, there is a refresh icon. I am using material UI for the icon. I want that after clicking on it, it should spin for a second.
I have no idea how to do it.

I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
refresh: {
    marginTop: "20px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    margin: "auto",
    animation: "spin 1s 1",
  },
  "@keyframes spin": {
    "0%": {
      transform: "translateY(-200%)",
    },
    "100%": {
      transform: "translateY(0)",
    },
  },
}));

function Refresh() {
    const [spin, setSpin] = React.useState(0);
    const classes= useStyles();
    
    const refreshCanvas = () => {
        setSpin(1);
        console.log("Refreshed");
    };
    return (
        <AutorenewIcon
            className={classes.refresh}
            onClick={refreshCanvas}
            onAnimationEnd={() => setSpin(0)}
            spin={spin}
        />
    )
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer... Thanx for both the answers I got here... I got the idea from those answers.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      refresh: {
        margin: "auto",
      },
      spin: {
        margin: "auto",
        animation: "$spin 1s 1",
      },
      "@keyframes spin": {
        "0%": {
          transform: "rotate(0deg)",
        },
        "100%": {
          transform: "rotate(360deg)",
        },
      }
    }))
    
    function Refresh() {
    const [spin, setSpin] = React.useState(0);
    
const classes= useStyles();

const refreshCanvas = () => {
    setSpin(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSpin(false);
    }, 1000);
    console.log("Refreshed");
};
return (
    <AutorenewIcon
        className={spin ? classes.spin : classes.refresh}
        onClick={refreshCanvas}
        spin={spin}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set the `spin` true on click and then add a `setTimeout` for `1000ms`, which will set that `spin` state again false. And then add a class conditionally based on the value of the `spin` state and add the animation to that class.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    refresh: {
        marginTop: "20px",
        cursor: "pointer",
        margin: "auto",
        "&.spin": {
            animation: "$spin 1s 1",
            // pointerEvents:'none'
        }
    },
    "@keyframes spin": {
        "0%": {
            transform: "rotate(0deg)"
        },
        "100%": {
            transform: "rotate(360deg)"
        }
    }
}));

function Refresh() {
    const [spin, setSpin] = React.useState(false);
    const classes = useStyles();

    const refreshCanvas = () => {
        setSpin(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setSpin(false);
        }, 1000);
    };

    return (
        <Autorenew
            className={clsx({
                [classes.refresh]: true,
                spin: spin
            })}
            onClick={refreshCanvas}
            spin={360}
        />
    );
}
```

*Optional Update*: *Also you can add `pointerEvents:"none"` in `spin` class to disable the click for that period of time until the animation is going which is `1000ms` here.*

Here is the working demo:
[image: Edit amazing-burnell-m9j4y]

Comment: I have opened it in codesandbox. I found that the animation is working once only when the site is loaded but not on clicking on the icon.

Comment: ohh!! actually, my last changes weren't saved in the codesanbox.. sorry for that!! Here the initial state of `spin` should be `false`. check now

Comment: What is `clsx` here ?

Comment: [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) is used for adding classNames conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Seprate the class of animaion let's assume it is `refresh` as of now and stored in `classes.refresh`.

You can do it by conditionally applying `className` to your element

```
function Refresh() {
const [spin, setSpin] = React.useState(0);

const classes= useStyles();

const refreshCanvas = () => {
    setSpin(1);
    console.log("Refreshed");
};
return (
    <AutorenewIcon
        className={spin === 1 ? classes.refresh : ''}
        onClick={refreshCanvas}
        onAnimationEnd={() => setSpin(0)}
        spin={spin}
    />
)
}
```

Comment: Not Working! How will css got to know that now it has to perform some animation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111813/how-can-i-animate-a-react-js-component-onclick-and-detect-the-end-of-the-animati

Comment: Edited my answer this will solve your problem for sure.