# How to hide children while changing width in css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation

I have a feature in my React app that allows users to see a UI in both mobile and desktop sizes. I have my `wrapper` and I change the `width` of it by using classes like this:

```
 .wrapper.desktop {
   width: 720px;
  }

.wrapper.mobile {
   width: 320px
  }
```

I also animated changes of width by using:

```
transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;
```

Now, the problem is that I want to fade the children and content of my `wrapper` while changing the `width` to have smooth animation and a loading overflow. Is it possible to use CSS and how? If not, is it possible in React and how?

Comment: It is not clear as to what you want

Comment: use `@keyframes` for the anmiation and simply declare `visibility. hidden` at 0% and `visibility: visible` at 100%

Comment: @RohitGupta I want to hide the content of my `wrapper` while width-changing animation is performing.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111813/how-can-i-animate-a-react-js-component-onclick-and-detect-the-end-of-the-animati